# What folders are necessary in flashdrive?

Tags: bootable-media

I just bought a flash drive and I want to turn it into a boot drive. It came preinstalled with a bunch of folders and files though and I'm not sure if I can delete them or not. Here's the list

--

club application

Scan Disc Secure Access

autorun

RunClubSanDisk

Run San Desck Secure Access_Win

--

I'm assuming I can get rid of the scans but what about the club and autorun? Do I need autorun if I am going to be booting a program on computer start up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of the data on the drive is necessary for the drive to function.  You can remove it all if you don't want it.

Autorun just starts the various applications that are pre-installed on the disk - even if you choose to keep any of the apps, you don't need autorun.

In fact, if you use this flash disk as a boot disk, you'll probably end up partitioning and formating the disk anyway, which will wipe anything on it.

You can copy it all off first if you think you might like to take a look at it later.

Comment: Nope sounds legit to me. Removing all the files! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If this is a normal flashdrive that you only use it for storage and no other special purposes then it's safe to remove all existing files and folders or even reformat the drive.

How To make it bootable is another matter and depends on what OS would you want to boot, normally they comes with tools to do such thing and they just need an empty drive to start with.

Comment: Well i'm booting backtrack so I imagine it will be fine once I convert to NTFS